# How To Scrape Each Line?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Traditionally, I use beautifulsoup to parse line by line.

That doesnt seem to work in this case and just prints blanks for me.

I want the link and the title of each job posting

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


url='https://oysterpointrx.com/careers/'
r=requests.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
content=soup.find_all('div',class_= 'opening')
for item in content:
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you wanna do to scrape the content you are after:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://boards.greenhouse.io/embed/job_board'
params = {
    'for': 'oysterpointpharma',
    'b': 'https://oysterpointrx.com/careers/'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.select('.opening > a'):
        item_title = item.get_text(strip=True)
        item_link = item.get("href")
        print(item_title,item_link)
```

Comment: beautiful, this worked! Is there a way to get the href/url of these titles?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `<Response [403]>` which means forbidden. You can check this by running `print(r)` after you declare the variable.

Comment: is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Realizing now that I should have commented this instead of posting as an answer. I'm not well-versed with Beautiful Soup, but I had a hunch that your request was getting an error. SIM's answer, as you've seen, solves the issue.